# Generating random string in command prompt

Tags: file, random, cmd

I want to be able to generate random strings from the windows command prompt. This is so that i can create a temp file with that random name so that i am sure that the temp file absolutely does not exist.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible via the normal command prompt. However, you could write a script to accomplish the task.

If you were using powershell this woul be simple:

```
$tempFileName = [System.IO.Path]::GetTempFileName()
```

generates (for Windows 7)

> C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpAE1C.tmp

Answer (score -1):

I finally wrote something like this..not very neat, but nevertheless serves the purpose.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set TMP_COUNT=0
:GET_TEMP_FILE
    if exist temp!TMP_COUNT!.txt (
        set /a TMP_COUNT+=1
        goto GET_TEMP_FILE
    ) 

    setlocal disabledelayedexpansion
echo temp file name is : temp!TMP_COUNT!.txt
```

Comment: You don't need delayed expansion here.